# How to analyse a suspicious Encapsulated Postscript file?

Tags: exploit

How can you analyze an encapsulated PostScript file that has a standard header, but is **way too big**?

There is a EPS file which has a size of 1.8MB. When it is reconverted to EPS, the resulting file is *1.5MB smaller*. The header of the converted and the original file look exactly the same, just the bytes that are interpreted are different.